# Replace zero and extreme values with missing

Tags: python, transformation, sensors, data-cleaning

I am working with a dataset 233 x 398,756 that represents sensor readings taken over a period. There are very many zeros and extreme (negative) values, due to sensor failures and malfunction. Any help with a python script that can convert these zeros and extreme values to missing/blank spaces in the cleaned dataset.
Many thanks.

Comment: Please improve your question. What have you tried so far? How does your current script look like? How do you store your data/dataset in python (list, NumPy array, pandas dataset)? What are extreme values(>10, >10000)?

Comment: @ wychmaster, i am working with pandas. df.replace(to_replace ="0.00", 
                 value ="Nan")